# Getting status of the nodes under Torque resource manager?

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc, torque

How can I get information about the status of the computational nodes on the torque-managed cluster (I am interested in the number of nodes that are allocated for jobs vs. idle ones)? Under SLURM I would use `sinfo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would normally use "pbsnodes -a" and then parse the output for what you'd like. See [this](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/suite/8-0/basic/help.htm#topics/torque/commands/pbsnodes.htm)

Comment: Thanks. For posterity, for my aims I used: `pbsnodes -a | grep " state =" | sort | uniq -c`